# Why is this element overlapping the one before (sorry, again)?

Tags: css, html

This is the code:

```
<form id="the_form" action="">ev
</div>
<!-- final pay_block -->
<div class="linea"/>
<div class="spacer"/>
```

the linea is overlapping the buy button, now is in the middle because there is margin-bottom: 15px aplied.

Edit:

This is the site: http://tinyurl.com/cboyymm

also what I want is to display the pay button in the same position. I left space enough to product description, and I fixed a height to the diferents divs before. Is this the right thing? I want to make it in the most minimalism way. Tips are very welcome, as Im using this project to learn.

Thanks in advance. At first I was afraid of posting things here because I didn´t want to mess, and Im quite ashame Im so nob. But I found a very warm welcome. Dont want to abuse, just know why this little things happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now define `min-height`

```
#pay_block {
    min-height: 78px;  // add this line 
height:78px;  // remove this line

}
```

Line No :- **612** in this css file **tienda1.css**

Result is this

[image]

Comment: That is the right answer. Also I found there was to height size aplied, one for the form, and another for the payblock. I still dont understand why this happened, but thanks very much to solve it and give me the tips to find it out.

Comment: Also is amazing how you middle-east guys are so cool with coding. Almost all the best tutorial I found, and many help, comes from middle-east people. Don´t get me wrong, is not racism, is admiration. The best tutorial I found about tabs ever is this one, the one I followed for the site: http://www.republicof3.com/how-to-create-tabs-in-html-using-jquery/